# echo (shell) and C language

Tags: c++, c, bash, shell

I have a program written in C language. In this program, I have an integer variable QS. The value of this variable changes during execution of the program
In this program written in C, I want to display this variable QS using the echo command shell

I heard about the system () function of the diaper C gives hand to use the terminal or console

system ("echo $ QS") when I do that, the variable QS is not recognized and it displays nothing.

Do you have any specific answers on how I could do this? and how to recognize the variable in C language?

I know that with a simple printf, I can display this variable, but what I want is to use  echo.

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: You don;t want to use echo. Just use printf().

Answer (score 3):

Shell can not access your program variable values. You have to set the value into the environment first. There are different ways to do this. One of them is (works in linux/unix)

```
int main()  
{  
    char chProgramVar[] = "hello world" ;  
    setenv("ShellVar", chProgramVar, 1) ;  
    system("echo $ShellVar") ;  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, the shell can't access your program variables. You can use `sprintf` to insert the value into the command that you will execute using `system`:

```
char command[BUFSIZ];

sprintf(command, "echo %d", QS);
system(command);
```

Answer (score 1):

The shell you're spawning with the `system(3)` call has no idea about any of the variables in your C program.  The easiest way to do what you want is to export your data as an environment variable.  Since the environment is inherited by the call to `system(3)`, you can just set the variable with [`setenv(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/setenv).  However, you must first format it as a string:

```
int QS = ...;
char QSStr[32];  // Longest integer string is INT_MIN = -2147483648, assuming
                 // that sizeof(int) == 4
snprintf(QSStr, sizeof(QSStr), "%d", QS);  // Convert to string
setenv("QS", QSStr);  // Set the environment variable)
...
system("echo $QS");  // Will print the value of QS
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to format the number as a character byte. The number "4" has a different integer representation as a printed character.

Use printf to print the number, or sprintf to reformat it as a character into a new buffer. Then you can print the new buffer using system echo (for whatever reason).

```
char s[16]; // might be too small
sprintf(s, "%d", integer_var); 
// s is the string
```

Comment: He said he doesn't want to use `printf`.

Comment: The example isn't using printf.

Comment: But you haven't shown how to use `echo` to do it, either. All you did was change the variable from integer to string.

Comment: I don't think the system echo call is well motivated in the question, being a useless call in itself. But this will need doing regardless of where the value goes to display.

Comment: Yeah, it seems like a pretty silly requirement. But if you're going to post an answer, it should answer the question he asked. Non-answers should be posted as comments.